# My threads never finish after context switching

Tags: c, multithreading

So I am working on context switching to make my own thread library. I'm running into a lot of difficulty though. I  have a queue created which I store contexts in so that when a process is yielded it may later continue. However it seems that the context I am popping is incorrect. I suspect that it may be due to my global currentContext variable not being properly assigned?

```
         ucontext_t* currentContext;

         void system_init() {
           createQueue();
           isRunning = 0;
         }

    int uthread_create(void (* func)()) {
       ucontext_t *context;
       context = (ucontext_t*)malloc(sizeof(ucontext_t));
       getcontext(context);
       context->uc_stack.ss_sp = malloc(16384);
       context->uc_stack.ss_size = 16384;

       makecontext(context, func, 0);
       if(isRunning == 0) {
           isRunning = 1;
           currentContext = context;
           setcontext(context);
           return 0;
       }
       else {
           push(context);
           return 0;
       }
       return -1;

}


   int uthread_yield() {
        push(currentContext);
        currentContext = pop();
        setcontext(currentContext);
   }
```

Here is how my code needs to be implemented:

```
int n threads=0;
int myid=0;
void do something()
{
     int id;
     id=myid;
     myid++;
     printf (”This is ult %d\n”, id); //just for demo purpose
     if(n threads<5){
          uthread create(do something);
          n threads++;
          printf (”ult %d yields \n”,id );
          uthread yield ();
          printf (”ult %d resumes \n”,id);
          uthread create(do something);
          n threads++;
     }
     printf (”ult %d starts I/O \n”,id);
     uthread startIO();
     sleep (2); //simulate some long−time I/O operation
     uthread endIO();
     printf (”ult %d returns from I/O \n”,id);
     uthread exit ();
     }

main()
{
     int i ;
     system init ();
     uthread create(do something);
     uthread exit ();
}
```

It has an expected output of:

```
This is ult 0
ult 0 yields
This is ult 1
ult 1 yields
ult 0 resumes
ult 0 starts I/O
This is ult 2
ult 2 yields
ult 1 resumes
ult 1 starts I/O
This is ult 3
ult 3 starts I/O
This is ult 4
ult 4 starts I/O
ult 2 resumes
ult 2 starts I/O
This is ult 5
ult 5 starts I/O
ult 0 returns from I/O
ult 1 returns from I/O
ult 3 returns from I/O
ult 4 returns from I/O
ult 2 returns from I/O
ult 5 returns from I/O
```

However my output is only:

```
This is ult 0
ult 0 yields
This is ult 1
ult 1 yields
This is ult 2
ult 2 yields
This is ult 3
ult 3 yields
This is ult 4
ult 4 yields
This is ult 5
ult 5 starts I/O
ult 5 returns from I/O
```

Which demonstrates that my threads are not resuming and instead just being skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are pushing data type `ucontext_t` into your queue. This is going to create copies of the `context` that you are putting into your queue, which is going to cause issues because you are stranding memory in the heap (not to mention abandoning the original `ucontext_t` you created).

Try having your queue store pointers of type `ucontext_t *` instead of `ucontext_t`'s. That way you don't strand memory and can access the process you originally created when you pop a context off of your queue.

Comment: I fixed those issues which were definitely causing some problems but I still am not having any lucky with the context resuming.

Comment: Is it possible that currentContext in the line `push(currentContext);` will have already finished whatever function it was executing by the time you push it onto the queue? That could potentially cause problems as well when then execute `setcontext(currentContext)` the next time that context comes up in the queue

Comment: I just updated my question to show how I am using the methods and what I expect for an output. The function definitely isn't being completed when I push and setcontext. I'm trying all kinds of stuff but it is getting me the same result.

Comment: Okay, here is the issue. When you call `uthread_yield();`, the function pushes the currentContext onto the queue for later execution - but what exactly is in `currentContext`? You haven't updated `currentContext` since you first created it with `getcontext()` and `makecontext()` via `uthread_create();` You need to make sure `uthread_yield()` saves the context as it was before swapping it off the processor. A function called `swapcontext()` might come in handy for that latter bit!